# Animation CSS3 (Slide scroll)

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm want to make a simple image slide scroll. 
It's going to work with a C# program. My CSS3 experience is rather low...
So I have a problem

My image slide scroll works perfectly with 4,5,6 images, but when I try a more images it doesn't work like it should.

Example 4 images

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='test.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\AC3SP%202014-08-26%2017-51-28-42.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\AC3SP%202014-08-26%2017-52-31-58.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-14%2014-33-59-36.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-14%2014-34-06-00.bmp></img>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.Slide {
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-animation: round 20s infinite;
animation: round 20s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes round 
{ 
    0% { opacity: 0}
    8% { opacity: 1}
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes round 
{
    0% { opacity: 0}
    8% { opacity: 1}
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
img:nth-child(2) {-webkit-animation-delay: 5s; animation-delay: 5s;}
img:nth-child(3) {-webkit-animation-delay: 10s; animation-delay: 10s;}
img:nth-child(4) {-webkit-animation-delay: 15s; animation-delay: 15s;}
```

**Problem: I use as example 14 images, you see the first image once. When the animation should restart you see the last one and then directly the second image...**

Example 14 images
HTML:

```
<html>
<head><link href='test.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></head>
<body>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\AC3SP%202014-08-26%2017-51-28-42.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\AC3SP%202014-08-26%2017-52-31-58.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-14%2014-33-59-36.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-14%2014-34-06-00.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-14%2014-34-11-92.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-16%2013-13-34-71.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-16%2013-13-46-53.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-16%2013-13-59-51.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-16%2013-24-28-15.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-16%2013-24-34-21.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-16%2013-49-43-91.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-16%2015-18-33-87.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\ACU%202014-11-16%2015-21-02-86.bmp></img>
<img class='Slide' src=F:\Fraps\Screenshots\Watch_Dogs%202014-10-28%2023-05-04-81.bmp></img>
</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
.Slide {
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-animation: round 70s infinite; 
animation: round 70s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes round 
{ 
    0% { opacity: 0}
    8% { opacity: 1}
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes round 
{
    0% { opacity: 0}
    8% { opacity: 1}
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

img:nth-child(2) {-webkit-animation-delay: 5s; animation-delay: 5s;}
img:nth-child(3) {-webkit-animation-delay: 10s; animation-delay: 10s;}
img:nth-child(4) {-webkit-animation-delay: 15s; animation-delay: 15s;}
img:nth-child(5) {-webkit-animation-delay: 20s; animation-delay: 20s;}
img:nth-child(6) {-webkit-animation-delay: 25s; animation-delay: 25s;}
img:nth-child(7) {-webkit-animation-delay: 30s; animation-delay: 30s;}
img:nth-child(8) {-webkit-animation-delay: 35s; animation-delay: 35s;}
img:nth-child(9) {-webkit-animation-delay: 40s; animation-delay: 40s;}
img:nth-child(10) {-webkit-animation-delay: 45s; animation-delay: 45s;}
img:nth-child(11) {-webkit-animation-delay: 50s; animation-delay: 50s;}
img:nth-child(12) {-webkit-animation-delay: 55s; animation-delay: 55s;}
img:nth-child(13) {-webkit-animation-delay: 60s; animation-delay: 60s;}
img:nth-child(14) {-webkit-animation-delay: 65s; animation-delay: 65s;}
```

Comment: Hmmm. I created [an example here](http://jsbin.com/wogoqa/1/edit?output) with the position absolute removed. I then watched each image cycle through and it worked perfectly. Chrome 39. What browser are you using and does my example have the same problem?

Comment: @misterManSam
I use Chrome 39. When I remove the postion absolute, it can see the first image everytime when the animation starts, so it works.
Still not understanding why I don't see the first image when I add my position:absolute back.

Comment: can you add to fiddle

Comment: @ChrysUgwu
Here is a fiddle with some random images
http://jsfiddle.net/2nuLbc91/

The same problems happens here to!
The blue sky wallpaper from WinXP ony shows once.

Comment: you might consider the slide effect not fade